# Laravel Function : In controller or in model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm wondering whats the better solution, to put all the function in my models files using Eloquent Query Builder or directly into the controller.

I've got a Table Donations with :
id, user_id, project_id and amount

A Table Users with :
Many field, but the one important is company_id

So, each employees has one company. But each employees can make several donations to several projects.

For example, I've got this function into my CompaniesController to show all the donation made by the employee of the selected company. :

```
// Total sum of all donates of the employees
    $total_sum = Donation
        ::join('users', 'donations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.company_id', $id)
        ->selectRaw('sum(donations.amount) as sum')
        ->first()
        ->toArray()['sum'];
```

It works fine, but I'm not sure how to convert it into a Eloquent Query Builder, I try :

```
 public function total_sum($company_id)
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Donation')
        ->join('users', 'donations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.company_id', $company_id)
        ->selectRaw('sum(donations.amount) as sum')
        ->first()
        ->toArray()['sum'];



}
```

But I get only the donation made by myself and not the other employees.

And for the records, whats the best solution ? To put all the function into controllers or into Model ?

Comment: You can use repository pattern. Here is a nice article https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scopes in your model to achieve what you want. Example

```
public function scopeTotalSum($query, $id)
{
    return $query->join('users', 'donations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.company_id', $id)
        ->selectRaw('sum(donations.amount) as sum');
}
```

then in you controller you can use it like this

```
$total_sum = Donation::totalSum($id)->first()->toArray()['sum'];
```

i think you can change the above line to this;

```
$total_sum = Donation::totalSum($id)->first()->sum;
```

hope it helps